# Spritekit - UITouch effect does not work when SKparticles are taking place over the area

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have a bubble, when touched will pop. This pop effects work fine with the code below. However when a spritekit particle effect is used which covers the bubble, the touch action does not work. When the particle effect finishes, the touch action will work. Does the particle effect have a non-touch field? and is there anyway around this? I attempted to change the z-position but that did not work.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKLabelNode *touchedNode = (SKLabelNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:positionInScene];

if ([[touchedNode name] isEqualToString:@"bubbleBall1"]) {
        ballNode.position = bubble1.position;
        [_gameNode addChild:ballNode];
        [bubble1 removeFromParent];
        [self playBubblePopSound];
    }
}
```

This is the particle effect im using in the physics contact area.

```
    SKEmitterNode *starCollectParticle = [SKEmitterNode emitterNamed:@"starCollect"];
    starCollectParticle.position = star1Node.position;
    starCollectParticle.zPosition = 0;
    //starCollectParticle.particleLifetime = 2;
    [self addChild:starCollectParticle];
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the z.position. I change the z.position of the particles. This did not work. However also changing the z.position of the SKSpritenode did the trick.

```
-(void)addBubble1:(CGPoint)pos{
gameObjects = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"GameObjects.atlas"];
bubble1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[gameObjects textureNamed:kBubble]];
bubble1.size = bubble1.texture.size;
bubble1.size = CGSizeMake(70,70);
bubble1.position = pos;
bubble1.name = bubble1CategoryName;
**bubble1.zPosition = 1;**
bubble1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:bubble1.frame.size.width/2];
bubble1.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
bubble1.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
bubble1.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
bubble1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = bubble1Category;
bubble1.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask =  ballCategory | completeObjectNodeCategory | completeObjectBoxNodeCategory;
bubble1.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = completeObjectNodeCategory | lineNodeCategory;
[_gameNode addChild:bubble1];
```

}

```
SKEmitterNode *starCollectParticle = [SKEmitterNode emitterNamed:@"starCollect"];
starCollectParticle.position = star1Node.position;
**starCollectParticle.zPosition = 0;**
//starCollectParticle.particleLifetime = 2;
[self addChild:starCollectParticle];
```